# Change font in Stack Exchange question advertisements to support a wider range of Unicode characters

Tags: feature-request, advertising, unicode, encoding

I recently came across this ad on Stack Overflow referencing [a question on the Spanish Language and Usage site](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/whats-the-meaning-of-y-yo-voy-y-me-lo-creo):

[image: Ad for question on Spanish Language and Usage]

Note that the text should have been rendered as (emphasis mine on the quotes):

> What's the meaning of **“**Y yo voy y me lo creo**”**?

Note that the quotes are not ASCII code `0x22` (") (which is commonly used for double-quotes) but Unicode characters `0x201C` and `201D;` which represent the left and right double-quotes respectively.

While this is a small example and it can be corrected by simply changing the quotes to use the ASCII double-quote character, it's more of an issue because there are currently five sites in beta for languages which foreign language characters and [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) for which ads could be displayed for:

- [German Language and Usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/)
- [Japanese Language and Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)
- [French Language and Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/)
- [Spanish Language and Usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)
- [Chinese Language and Usage](http://chinese.stackexchange.com)

Add to that there are currently over 15 other language and usage sites proposed on Area 51 which use characters that won't render well in this current font, so the chances of this happening increase if or when those sites come online.